# How to remove line gaps from oracle database columns

Tags: sql, oracle

In my database, where I pull the data from dblink. 
The data gets inserted successfully, but when I copy the data from the fields anywhere, it comes with a line gap.

How to remove the linegaps in between the column values?

eg:

my data in database is:

```
   0232493, VAS Item, SONY
```

when I copy from database and paste in any editor, it comes as:

```
 0232493, VAS
    Item, SONY
```

Comment: I dont understand your question, show us an example?

Comment: I have added the example in the question.

Comment: How do you copy the data? What client are you copying it from? Are you certain their is no `/n` or `/r` hanging out in the data when you insert it?

Comment: There might be a /n in the source data. 
is there any way to remove it?

Comment: Look up `REPLACE`.

Comment: Do you want to fix it in the database, by updating the stored value, or only in display? Also, if your table is called t and the column is c, what do you get, for example, with   SELECT DUMP(c) FROM t WHERE c LIKE '0232493%'   ?   This command will show you the ASCII code for the stored string; you will be able to see character numbers 13 and 10 for new line, and who knows what else.  What operating system do you use?

Comment: This is best handled in the application where you intend to display the data.  What application is that?

Comment: @DanBracuk - why is that?   If the data really shouldn't have the line breaks, why should every single application have to work around it, instead of fixing it just once, in the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to understand what unexpected character you have in your strings; probably `chr(13)` and/or `chr(10)`.
You can check this way:

```
SQL> select '0232493, VAS
  2      Item, SONY'
  3  from dual ;

'0232493,VASITEM,SONY'
--------------------------------
0232493, VAS
    Item, SONY


SQL> select dump('0232493, VAS
  2      Item, SONY')
  3  from dual ;

DUMP('0232493,VASITEM,SONY')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=27: 48,50,51,50,52,57,51,44,32,86,65,83,10,32,32,32,32,73,116,101,109
,44,32,83,79,78,89
```

Typ=96 Len=27: 48,50,51,50,52,57,51,44,32,86,65,83,**10**,32,32,32,32,73,116,101,109
    ,44,32,83,79,78,89

Here in the example I have `chr(10)`, so I remove it with replace:

```
SQL> select replace('0232493, VAS
  2      Item, SONY', chr(10), '')
  3  from dual;

REPLACE('0232493,VASITEM,SONY',CHR(10),'')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0232493, VAS    Item, SONY
```